# How to run the grails default commands from a custom script in grails

Tags: grails

I need to run the grails default commands like `clean`, `compile`, `prod war` using the code.
I am created a custom script in my project and i need to run these commands through codes. 
My custom script is given below.

```
class CustomDeploy extends Script {
    def run() {
            // my code for running commands.
        }
}
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Grails script, which has access to gradle.

http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/commandLine.html#creatingCustomScripts